# Undefined symbols for mac ocaml build

Tags: macos, ocaml, ctypes, libffi

I've been trying to compile a recent application that uses `ctypes` and `sqlexpr`, but I'm having trouble with symbols not being resolved.  I built ctypes and sqlexpr from OPAM, and have updated versions of `libffi` from brew, but don't understand why I might not be getting the correct library linkage.  Anyone care to take a guess?  (I've already tried my typical fix for this, which is to pass in `CFLAGS="-arch i386"`)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ffi_closure_alloc", referenced from:
      _ctypes_make_function_pointer in libctypes-foreign-base_stubs.a(ffi_call_stubs.o)
  "_ffi_prep_closure_loc", referenced from:
      _ctypes_make_function_pointer in libctypes-foreign-base_stubs.a(ffi_call_stubs.o)
  "_sqlite3_enable_load_extension", referenced from:
      _caml_sqlite3_enable_load_extension in libsqlite3_stubs.a(sqlite3_stubs.o)
     (maybe you meant: _caml_sqlite3_enable_load_extension)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Error while building custom runtime system
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 41 targets (40 cached) in 00:00:00.
make: *** [all] Error 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/issues/398, looks like this is a problem with the sqlite on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

> "switching the order in which packages are specified resolves the issue"

Comment: Thanks, I actually found that out several hours ago, but I appreciate the insight and want to keep the answer here for history!

Answer (score 0):

To answer this, I took Thomas Leonard's solution and also had to install a new version of `libffi` on my mac.  I had to force link `libffi` in brew, and removed the version of `libffi` in `/usr/lib/libffi.dylib`, and pointed it at my version in brew's cellar.  After doing these, along with switching the OCamlBuild package order, things worked out successfully.